# ResponseText on Login Java Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I want to make a Login and on failure I want to write on a div "wrong password" but on success redirect on response.sendRedirect(".html "); it just includes the html page requested withing the  existing one . How can I do such a thing ?

```
xhr.onload = function (){
if (xhr.status === 200) {
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = xhr.responseText; 
alert(password); 
} else if (xhr.status !== 200) { 
alert('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status); 
}
```

The thing is I am doing this on ajax requests and I m giving as a responsetext the div for failure but in success it doesn't redirect it just goes having an html withing an html

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from members where PatientEmail=? and PatientPassword=?");
            ps.setString(1, email);
            ps.setString(2, pass);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                flag=1;
                response.sendRedirect("InnerIndexRedesign.html");
                //request.getRequestDispatcher("InnerIndexRedesign.html").forward(request, response);

            }
        out.println("Wrong username or password.");
```

Comment: Questions asking for help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish this is by using query strings. If a login attempt is unsuccessful, your url may look like `http://localhost:8080/login?attempt=failure`. Then in your HTML page, you could check for the value of `attempt` and if it equals `failure`, you could display a message.

For the redirect, you could do the same thing. Evaluate for the value of another query key, then if the value of `attempt` equals `success`, you would redirect to the value of that key which would store the redirect url.

Comment: xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById('response')
                   .innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
           alert(password);
        } else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
The thing is I am doing this on ajax requests and I m giving as a responsetext the div for failure  but in success it doesn't redirect it just goes having an html withing an html

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide your code, it would be easier to answer. Anyways, you could do something like this:

HTML part

```
<p id="error"></p>
```

JS part

```
var err = document.getElementById('error');
if(username-input == 'username' && userpassword-input == 'password'){
  response.sendRedirect(".html");
} else {
   err.innerHTML = 'your username and/or password is not correct';
}
```

Comment: How can I do do such a thing in the js part unless I contact the mysql database on the Java ?I m doing this in java servlet .Can someone connect to mysql from js ?

Comment: I thought you had the login credentials stored somehow. And its not possible to connect to mysql/database using just js, in order to do that you must interact the js code with java somehow or use Node.js e.g.

If the problem is that you are getting the responseText on success inside the html page the login form is at, its probaly because you are not redirecting the user on success.

This will redirect the user to the redirectUri
var redirectUri = 'https://myurl.com';
if(xhr.status === 200){
window.location.href=redirectUri;
} else {
  // error
}

Comment: Sorry I am probably not making myself clear .I am already doing this in java I added java code in question. But on response.redirect page shows up within the already existing page

Comment: I see. It seems like the java method to redirect the user in client isnt working proparly. Im not that familiar with java so maybe someone with better java skills can answer you on this.